# Trouble responding JQuery Ajax post request to express.js node.js

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, post, express

This is the express.js server code:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
app.listen(8001);

app.configure(function(){

   app.use(express.bodyParser());
   app.set('views',__dirname + '/views');
   app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
   app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
   app.use(express.cookieParser());
   app.use(app.router);

});

app.get('/', function (req, res){

   res.render('ajax.ejs');

});

app.post('/ajax', function (req, res){

   console.log(req.body);
   res.contentType('json');
   console.log(JSON.stringify({response:'json'}));
   res.write(JSON.stringify({response:'json'}));
   res.end();

 });
```

And this the code from `ajax.ejs`:

```
<html>
<head>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>    

</head>
<body>


 <form>
   <input type="button" id="enter" value="Enter">
 </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#enter').click(function(){  
    $.ajax({ 
               url: '/ajax'
             , type: 'POST'
             , cache: false
             , data: { field1: 1, field2: 2 }
             , complete: function() {
             //called when complete
                 console.log('process complete');
             },

             success: function(data) {
                 alert(data);
                 console.log('process sucess');
              },

             error: function() {
                console.log('process error');
              },
           });
         });            

  </script>
</body> 
</html>
```

What I'm trying is to responde the AJAX post req, but when `ajax.ejs` show me the data in an alert that the server send, the result is this `[object Object]`. Where's the problem here?

Thanks advance!

Comment: Is there a problem? `data` should be your JSON object `{response:'json'}`. `alert(JSON.stringify(data))`, or `console.log(data)` might be better debugging options for you.

Comment: True! Now show it properly. Thanks!

Comment: You should also be using res.json() instead